# Add AdBanner globally to all screens

Tags: ios, swift, admob

Is there a way to add on AdBanner for the whole App? For example like with a PageViewController to all its childs.

But is it possible to add one AdBanner globally?

If so, is there a way to additionally skip one?

Comment: Create a UIViewController subclass with the banner.

Comment: How would you exactly implement this in code?

Comment: Do you want to show the ad banner in the bottom of all view controllers?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Yes, and above the bottom safe area for all newer devices, since I assume that's not allowed.

Comment: Didn't have time yet, will do it later this day.

Answer (score -1):

You can add it as a subview to app window

```
let wind = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!
adBanner.tag = 22
wind.addSubview(adBanner)
```

Then you can access the ad inside the one you need to hide and do

```
let ad = wind.viewWithTag(22) as! AdBanner
ad.isHidden = true/false
```

Comment: AdBanner will cover the content of view controllers

Comment: window subview will do that job

Comment: Alert views can be added in window, because alerts are temporary views and will be hidden once a option is selected. But Ad banners are permanent. It will hide the view controller contents. Adding add banner in window isn't good. UIViewController subclass should be used and each view controller constraints should consider this banner space

Comment: **Adding add banner in window isn't good** from where you say this ,  considered space in each vc should be anyway if there will be a banner with some predefined height , making a vc or view has no difference

Comment: When one of the view controller is embedded in a UITabBarController, the add banner will cover the tab bar buttons